# slow running postgres11 logical replication from EC2 to RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm trying to move a Postgres (11.6) database on EC2 to RDS (postgres 11.6). I started replication last a couple nights ago and have now noticed the replication has slowed down considerably when I see how fast the database size in increasing on the subscriber `SELECT pg_database_size('db_name')/1024/1024`. Here are some stats of the environment:

Publisher Node:

```
Instance type: r5.24xlarge
Disk: 5Tb GP2 with 16,000 PIOPs
Database Size w/ pg_database_size/1024/1024: 2,295,955 mb
```

Subscriber Node:

```
Instance type: RDS r5.24xlarge
Disk: 3Tb GP2
```

Here is the current DB size for the subscriber and publisher:

```
Publisher:
SELECT pg_database_size('db_name')/1024/1024 db_size_publisher;
 db_size_publisher
-------------------
           2295971
(1 row)

Subscriber:
SELECT pg_database_size('db_name')/1024/1024 as db_size_subscriber;
 db_size_subscriber
--------------------
            1506348
(1 row)
```

The difference is still about 789GB left to replicate it seems like and I've noticed that the subsriber db is increasing at a rate of about `250kb/sec`

```
db_name=> SELECT pg_database_size('db_name')/1024/1024, current_timestamp;
 ?column? |       current_timestamp
----------+-------------------------------
  1506394 | 2020-05-21 06:27:46.028805-07
(1 row)

db_name=> SELECT pg_database_size('db_name')/1024/1024, current_timestamp;
 ?column? |       current_timestamp
----------+-------------------------------
  1506396 | 2020-05-21 06:27:53.542946-07
(1 row)
```

At this rate, it would take another 30 days to finish replication, which makes me think I've set something up wrong.

Here are also some other stats from the publisher and subscriber:

Subscriber pg_stat_subscription:

```
db_name=> select * from pg_stat_subscription;
 subid |    subname     |  pid  | relid | received_lsn  |      last_msg_send_time       |     last_msg_receipt_time     | latest_end_lsn |        latest_end_time
-------+----------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------+-------------------------------
 21562 | rds_subscriber |  2373 | 18411 |               | 2020-05-20 18:41:54.132407-07 | 2020-05-20 18:41:54.132407-07 |                | 2020-05-20 18:41:54.132407-07
 21562 | rds_subscriber | 43275 |       | 4811/530587E0 | 2020-05-21 06:15:55.160231-07 | 2020-05-21 06:15:55.16003-07  | 4811/5304BD10  | 2020-05-21 06:15:54.931053-07
(2 rows)
```

At this rate...it would take weeks to complete....what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have indexes not needed for replication?

Comment: so I removed the indexes just this morning and am running it again...and I'm seeing the same behavior...I saw the db on the subscriber increasing at around 50mb/sec...but now its down to 12mb/sec...I also removed triggers and constraints on the tables too

Comment: I don't know what would explain that other than indexes being randomly updated and becoming too large to fit in memory.

Comment: Hey, were you able to find the root cause for this and fix the replication speeds?